# Equation of motion of a spring (Applied mathematics)

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I'm having a bit of trouble with this problem. Mostly trying to label sufficient variables for the system.

> A body moves in a straight line on a smooth horizontal table. The body is attacked to one end of a spring of length $l_0$ and modulus of elasticity $\lambda$. The other end of the spring is fixed. Write down the equation of motion.

With systems like these I always try to draw a diagram and label it to make it more intuitive and understandable.

[image]

Where $x$ is the displacement of the body from the fixed point $O$.Edit:  Where the spring is attached to the wall. I forgot to add it in my diagram.

$$F_{net}= m\ddot{x}= -kx=-k(l-l_0)$$

Is this labelling correct?

$$m\ddot{x}= -\dfrac{\lambda}{l_0}(l-l_0)$$

where $k=\dfrac{\lambda}{l_0}$

$$\boxed {\ddot{x}+\dfrac{\lambda}{ml_0}x= \dfrac{\lambda}{m}}$$

> (b) Obtain the energy equation

$$\int{m\ddot{x}}= \int{F(x)}$$

Multiplying both sides by $\dot{x}dt$ allows to integrate $F(x)$ w.r.t $x$.

$$\begin{align}
\int{m\dot{x}d\dot{x}} & = \int{Fdx} \\
\int{m\dot{x}d\dot{x}} & = \int{-kx} \\
\dfrac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2 +C & = -\dfrac{kx^2}{2} + D
\end{align}$$

where $C$ and $D$ are constants of integration. Rearranging gives us the energy equation.

$$\boxed{\dfrac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2 +\dfrac{kx^2}{2} =E}$$

> (c) The body is released from rest when the spring length is $\dfrac{l_0}{3}$. Sow that the maximum velocity of the body during the subsequent motion is $\dfrac{2}{3}\sqrt{\dfrac{\lambda l_0}{m}}$

To solve this problem we need to use the conservation of energy. Which states

$$K.E_i + P.E_i = K.E_f + P.E_f$$

We are told the the initial velocity is 0 and the length of the spring is $\dfrac{l_0}{3}$ at that time. The maximum velocty occurs when the **kinetic energy** is a maximum - when the potential energy is a minimum ($x=0$)

$$\dfrac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2_0+\dfrac{k\Big(\dfrac{l_0}{3}^2\Big)}{2}= \dfrac{1}{2}m\dot{x}_{max}^2 +\dfrac{k(0)}{2}$$

The initial Kinetic energy goes to $0$ and the final potential energy does to $0$.Leaving

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{1}{2}m\dot{x}_{max}^2 & = \dfrac{k\Big(\dfrac{l_0}{3}^2\Big)}{2} \\
m\dot{x}_{max}^2 & = \dfrac{\lambda l_0}{9m}\\
\dot{x}_{max} & = \dfrac{1}{3}\sqrt{\dfrac{\lambda l_0}{m}} \\
\end{align}$$

I've gone wrong somewhere, I don't know if my assumption of $x=0$ is correct. That's why I think my labelling is incorrect and I think it's very important for me to figure this out.

> (d) The body is given a velocity $V$ when the spring length is $l_0$.Find the maximum  of the spring in the subsequent motion.

The maximum length of the spring is when the P.E is a maximum so when the K.E is $0$. Again we are given the conditions with initial velocity = $V$ and the starting position to be at equilibrium $l_0$. I used the conservation of energy again and I got the result

$$x_{max} = \sqrt{\dfrac{ml_0 V^2}{\lambda}+l_0}$$

That was when I plugged my values in for initial velocity and initial position. The same as in part (c) but with maximum distance this time.

> (e)Find the minimum length of the spring.

I'm not so sure how to find the minimum length. Do I get the minimum by subtitling the maximum from something?

Thanks for looking over it, I struggled quite a bit with this one even thought the maths isn't the hardest. I can't seem to label it with confidence.

Comment: Why don''t you try standard SHM equation? $x=l_o \cos(\omega t)$? as the equation of motion for the spring

Comment: cause I don't know how to do it that way. Exam is on Monday and I still have a lot to study unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part (c), the spring length is $\frac{l_0}{3}$, which means the spring is compressed by $\frac{2l_0}{3}$. You got the two mixed up, hence getting the wrong answer. I believe Part (d) and (e) has the same conditions, so the maximum and minimum lengths are $$ l_0\  \pm \  \sqrt{\frac{ml_0v^2}{\lambda}} $$

Comment: Of course!! Thanks a million. Silly mistake. Thanks very much Mr Lee.

Comment: Glad to help! I haven't studied physics for over four years, and it's very interesting to read something like this again. :)

Comment: Great memory! Unfortunately I live over 100km from college and this website is my math tutor. The people here are amazing and rigorous :)